# Back button closes app after navigation but not before

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I've got an xamarin forms/prism app, and my hardware back button does nothing on the initial page.

If I navigate to another page, it closes the app as expected. If I navigate to the initial page again, it also closes the app - but not if the app just started.

Is there something I'm missing?

My `class App` mainly has an `OnInitialized` that navigates to the initial page:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync( "MyMasterDetail/MyNavigationPage/StartPage", animated: false );
}
```

On `MyMasterDetail`, there are buttons that navigate to `MyNavigationPage/SettingsPage` and other pages like that.

It doesn't matter if I use Android 5 in Emulator or Android 6 on a real device, the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When using a MasterDetail as your root, you are not actually navigating anywhere else. You are simply changing the Detail property of the MasterDetail to another Page.  This is not a navigation action.  So you are not really navigating.  If you want to fake it, you need to add the INavigationPageOptions to your MyNavigationPage and set the ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation property to false.  This will continuously push new pages onto the MasterDetailPage.Detail MyNavigationPage without clearing the stack (PopToRoot).  Then this will allow your bac button to behave like you are wanting.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right - if I do not clear the stack upon navigating somewhere, the back button will close my app when I haven't done any navigation yet?

Comment: No, if you don't clear the stack the back button will work as expected because you are adding pages to the navigation stack.  If you DO clear the stack your back button will close your app, because you will have nothing on your navigation stack except your root MasterDetailPage

Comment: I think, there's a misunderstanding. I _want_ the back button to close the app. But it _doesn't_ close it, unless I "navigate"/change the detail property once.

Comment: That's weird because it closes for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it did for me, too, when I worked at the project last time, a few weeks ago. I updated the whole xamarin forms and android nuget packages in between, though.

Comment: Update: starting from today, my app closes (once again) when pressing the back button, without navigating first.